# turtlebot_calibration isn't working as expected

Tags: ros, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot isn't a turtlebot, but it's very close / uses many turtlebot parts.

I'm trying to run the turtlebot calibration routine. On the first step, it rotates 360 degrees. On the second, it only makes it half way, 180 degrees.

Alternativly, I can set odom_angular_scale_correction so that it goes 2 full circles the first step and the other speeds only go one.

Any idea what would cause the lower speed s the higher speeds to be completely off?

[edit] I replaced the create and the power/gyro board without and changes, so it's probably sotware [/edit]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30990/turtlebot_calibration-isn%27t-working-as-expected/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-04-02**:
Dropping the update_rate of turtlebot_node to 10 instead of 30 made it perform a lot better in the calibration, but the rotation still seems way off when I actually drive the robot around..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is supposed to turn 720 the first time then 360 the following times.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1